# The Spock compiler plugin could not run because

Tags: java, groovy, spring-security, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spock

Was trying to complete tutorial here: http://rwinch.blogspot.com/2011/03/running-spring-securitys-tutorial.html

Have downloaded git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security.git and got a lot of projects inside Spring Source ToolSuite. Two of them are contain error (`spring-security-config` and `spring-security-samples-cassample`)

> Groovy:Unexpected problem with AST transform: The Spock compiler
>   plugin could not run because Spock 0.5.0-groovy-1.7 is not compatible
>   with Groovy 1.8.4. For more information, see
>   http://versioninfo.spockframework.org

The error it attached to the line

```
package org.springframework.security.config.http
```

I am absolutely unfamiliar with Groovy. So is it possible to hint me what simple thing to do for upgrade Spock 0.5.0-groovy-1.7 somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Solved by adding command line option

```
 -groovy.compiler.level 17
```

to STS shortcut.

According to here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiler+Switching+within+Groovy-Eclipse